# Basic example of Map in Erlang

Tags: erlang

Day 2 of learning Erlang. I am trying to learn the basics of using Map in Erlang by creating a simple map function that takes in any predicate and list (passed in by the user) and checks if the the predicate returns true or false and stores the result in the list.

So if the user passes in `(> 3)` as the predicate and the list contains `[3,4,5]` the desired output would be `[false, true, true]`.

This is what I tried:

```
applyMap (P, LST) -> lists:map(P LST).
```

I appreciate any suggestions on how to do this.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What is wrong with what you have tried?  I think you want your predicate to be something like this: `fun(x) -> x > 3 end`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am getting a syntax error with my implementation. What is X? where did you get it from? Note: The predicate is passed in by the user.

Comment: I'm not expert, but I think you want to pass an anonymous function such as `lists:map(fun(Val) -> Val > 3 end, LST).`  This returns `[false, true, true]`.

Comment: I have been using SML for a class project lately and have the `op` keyword for binary operator, but don't know if you could apply it to a greater than operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're just missing a `,` between `P` and `LST` in your call to `lists:map`.  Try this one:

```
applyMap (P, LST) -> lists:map(P, LST).
```

If you pass in the anonymous function `fun(X) -> X > 3 end` to your `applyMap`, you should get your desired output.

Example:

```
applyMap (fun(X) -> X > 3 end, LST).
```

Comment: +1, Thanks for the reply. Can you please show what the function call would be like when the user calls applyMap and passes in the arugments? I confused about how to pass in a predicate or any function, in Erlang?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So if the module name is `functions`, your method, is the only way a predicate can be passed to function applyMap? `funtions:applyMap(fun(X)->X > 3 end, [1,2,3]).` We can't do something like `functions:applyMap(>3, [1,2,3]).`??

Comment: You can assign functions to a variable, such as `Pred = fun(X) -> X > 3 end.` and then call `functions:applyMap(Pred, [1,2,3]).`. The predicate does have to be a function.

Comment: You can also write expressions that evaluate to named functions using the syntax `fun name/arity`, such as `fun lists:map/2`. This can be helpful when mapping an already-defined function over a list.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems: first, you're missing the comma between `P` and `LST`, but second, you can't use Haskell-style curried functions like `(> 3)`. `lists:map((> 3), [1,2,3])` isn't correct in Erlang.

In Haskell, `(> 3)` is the curried form of `\n -> n > 3`. In Erlang, you have to write it explicitly:

```
lists:map(fun(N) -> N > 3 end, [2,4,6])
```